# Twitter Bootstrap dropdown not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Any ideas why this Twitter Bootstrap dropdown isn't working?

Javascript in head:

```
<script src="/assets/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Menu HTML:

```
             <li class="dropdown">
                <a data-target="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown menu here...
                  <b class="caret"></b>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="/app/1">Item A</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/app/2">Item B</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/app/3">Item C</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
```

Comment: In what order is your js loaded in? jQuery goes first as always, bootstrap second.

Comment: If you have bootstrap.js (not bootstrap.min.js), you should *not* also add bootstrap-dropdown.js. That did the trick for me.

Comment: Try add to dom-ready: $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();

Comment: You don't need to tie it to the document ready function.  It works without any JavaScript.

Answer (score 7):

Put the dropdown class on a div that is wrapping the `li` rather than on the `li` itself. Like this...

```
        <div class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown trigger</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
         ...
        </ul>
        </div>
```

That example is from the [bootstrap site](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns)

Your code should look like this...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html >
    <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    <link href="../theme/bootstrap.css" rel=stylesheet type="text/css">

    </head>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <ul class="dropdown">
        <a data-target="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown menu here...
          <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="/app/1">Item A</a></li>
              <li><a href="/app/2">Item B</a></li>
              <li><a href="/app/3">Item C</a></li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I tried making a nested list, but it didn't work with bootstrap. I think it gets the two dropdowns confused.

Comment: I tried that and it looks awful. Plus it doesn't work. Checking their website, that's not how they're doing it. E.g. look here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns

Comment: I copy and pasted my example directly from their site. I don't understand what you mean. We need an example of your site to help an further.

Comment: This is the first code I've found that actually works.  Thanks.

Comment: For me this was important - both bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js contain all plugins in a single file. I was including bootstrap-dropdown.js and it wasn't working:)

Comment: If the dropdown is part of the navbar, twitter themselves suggest having the class inside of the list item. Inspect element on the navbar in the section "Within a navbar" at http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns

Comment: I have a similar problem. I copied the HTML markup from http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/ as is, updated the locations of the CSS and JS, put it in an ASP.net application. The dropdowns don't work and the alerts don't close. This is a new behaviour with BS3 as BS2 was working fine. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are using the latest version of JQuery

Answer (score 2):

This is easily solved.  The element wrapping your code is a li, but it needs to be a div.  This works for me:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a data-target="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown menu here...
    <b class="caret"></b>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="/app/1">Item A</a></li>
    <li><a href="/app/2">Item B</a></li>
    <li><a href="/app/3">Item C</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

If you want it to look like a button, just add "btn" to the class list like this:

`<a data-target="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle btn" href="#">`

My header section looks like this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css'>
<script src='js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js' type='text/javascript'>
<script src='js/bootstrap.min.js' type='text/javascript'>
```

You may want to leave out the responsive css if you're not doing anything for mobile devices.